# Portrait and Landscape Design

Tags: game-design, phaser

I have a turn-based game that is built with HTML 5 gaming framework and runs completely fine in Landscape mode. What I am trying to figure out is how to make the game run fine in both portrait and landscape mode such that even when the game is running and player rotates the screen to landscape the game runs perfectly or the game transition between landscape and portrait mode smoothly.

I can capture the orientation change event which is fired, my question is how should I design the game for both orientations.

Currently, I am trying to create a common file which then calls my separate orientation layouts created for the game but is this the right way?
Thanks

Comment: What do you want to happen when the orientation changes? What happens right now? How do these two outcomes differ?

Comment: since the game is designed for landscape mode so in portrait the game is scaled down to fit but this reduces the size of different sprites on the screen like buttons,
checkboxes and also sometimes space is left out, what I want is when the device rotates to portrait these sprites look clearly and bigger on the screen. Also, landscape design should remain like current one

Comment: That probably makes a lot more sense to someone who has seen your game. We have not, so you'll have to be more specific or include example images/diagrams in your question.

Comment: In order to advise you on how to design your gameplay to work in both orientations we would at least need to know the genre.